# Prestashop module error "An error occured. Please check your data."

Tags: php, ajax, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop version 1.6.1.17 .

I have a module called "Blockcallmeback". This module adds the option to the customer to leave his/her telephone number so you can call him/her back.

The problem is that after submitting the form, there is an error that says:

"An error occured. Please check your data."

Which means, the ajax function returns success = false, but I don't know why.

This is the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var blockcallme_url = "/casannabis/modules/blockcallme/ajax.php";
var blockcallme_text_please = "Please enter";
var blockcallme_text_please_phone = "your phone number";
var blockcallme_text_thanks = "Thank you. We will call you soon.";
var blockcallme_text_error = "An error occured. Please check your data.";
var blockcallme_mask = "+56 (9) 9999-9999";
$(function () {
    $("a.blockcallme_button").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.4,
        'padding': 0,
        afterShow: function () {
            $('#blockcallme_phone').focus();
            $('#blockcallme_phone').inputmask({
                'mask': blockcallme_mask,
                "clearMaskOnLostFocus": false
            });
        }
    });

    $('.blockcallme_form').on('submit', function () {
        debugger;
        $('#blockcallme_loader').show();
        var form = $(this);
        $('.blockcallme_errors').html('').hide();
        $('.blockcallme_success').html('').hide();
        var success = true;
        var blockcallme_phone_input = $(this).find('#blockcallme_phone');
        if (!blockcallme_phone_input.val() || !blockcallme_phone_input.inputmask('isComplete')) {
            blockcallme_phone_input.css('outline', '1px solid red');
            setTimeout(function () {
                blockcallme_phone_input.css('outline', '');
            }, 1000);
            $(this).find('.blockcallme_errors').append(blockcallme_text_please + ' <span style="font-weight: bold;">' + blockcallme_text_please_phone + '</span>.<br>').show();
            success = false;
        }
        if (!success) {
            $('#blockcallme_loader').hide();
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: blockcallme_url + '?ajax=1&rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(jsonData) {
                debugger;
                $('#blockcallme_loader').hide();
                if (jsonData['success'] == 1) {
                    form.find('.blockcallme_success').html(blockcallme_text_thanks).show();
                }
                else {
                    form.find('.blockcallme_errors').html(blockcallme_text_error).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the php code:

```
    <?php
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config/config.inc.php');
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../init.php');

    if(Tools::getValue('ajax') == 1)
    {
            $name = pSQL(trim(Tools::getValue('blockcallme_name', '')));
            $phone = pSQL(trim(Tools::getValue('blockcallme_phone', '')));
            $blockcallme = Module::getInstanceByName('blockcallme');

            $success = 0;

            if(!empty($phone))
            {
                    Context::getContext()->cookie->blockcallme_phone = $phone;
                    Context::getContext()->cookie->blockcallme_name = $name;
                    $template = 'blockcallme';
                    $template_vars = array(
                            '{name}' => $name,
                            '{phone}' => $phone,
                    );

                    $email = Configuration::get('CALLME_EMAIL') ? Configuration::get('CALLME_EMAIL') : Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL');
                    $to = array(
                            $email,
                    );

                    $send = Mail::Send(
                            Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),
                            $template,
                            $blockcallme->l('Callback request', 'ajax'),
                            $template_vars,
                            $to,
                            null,
                            Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'),
                            Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
                            null,
                            null,
                            dirname(__FILE__).'/mails/'
                    );

                    if($send)
                            $success = 1;
            }

            if($success)
                    die(json_encode(array('success' => 1)));
            else
                    die(json_encode(array('success' => 0)));
    }
```

Comment: Check the response in the network tab of your developer tools to see what you're getting back from the script.

Comment: Enable errors. I see that you have a `debugger` in your code. Which is the value for `jsonData`?

Comment: I have 2 debuggers, but the 2nd debugger doesn't work. If I check, it says: ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined.

Comment: Besides, in the network tab it says: Name: http://opencode.cl/casannabis/modules/blockcallme/ajax.php?ajax=1&rand=1519408487166; Status: (pending)

Comment: Why do you use 'die' instead of just return? In your javascript before checking jsonData['success'] you probably should decode json you get from php.

Comment: @Joint how can I do that? It's a module I downloaded

Comment: just replace 'die(json_decode...' with 'return json_decode...' and in javascript just after '$('#blockcallme_loader').hide();' add line "jsonData = $.parseJSON(jsonData);"

Comment: @Joint I still get the same error message when debugging and checking the jsonData value: ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined.

Comment: is it free module? can I get it somewhere?

Comment: @Joint additionally, now I got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null

Comment: ok, I didn't notice there is line "dataType : "json",", so my solution is incorrect, please return to default version

Comment: please add line "console.log(jsonData);" just before debugger inside success function and tell me what it returns in console

Comment: @Joint yes, here: https://presta.site/prestashop-modules/8-obratnyj-zvonok.html

Comment: @Joint this is what it returns and it is returned twice (I checked the js function is shown twice in the page sourcecode): {success: 0}

Comment: It looks like your server cannot send email, have you tried to send test email from backoffice?

Comment: @Joint I tried and it sent the test email

Comment: hmm... it the only place where it can fail... one more idea: starting line below 'if(!empty($phone))' paste code 'die(json_encode($something));' where $something is variable declared before that line and step by step move this line lower to see when you get something usefull in console.log in javascript

Comment: the most interesting should be return after send mail: 'die(json_encode($send));'